# How to upload the file in karate UI automation sing single button from desktop

Tags: user-interface, automation, karate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GA2We.png)By using below code I am able to navigate to desktop, but file is not being selected and unable to click on Open button.

enter image description here : In the first image I have only single button(Upload). I have to click and upload the file through this button only

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggrqE.png): In the second image`enter code here` I am able to navigate till provided path (Desktop), but able to select the file (Upload.docx) and perform submit operation.

Image 3: code snippet[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUqez.png)